# Will editing a file always have O(N) time complexity?

Tags: file, optimization, lua, time-complexity

I was writing a Lua script to read, browse, and edit a large text file. The approach I chose was to 'page through' the file, reading a segment into a buffer variable, then editing it or moving to the next page.

This works great for reading the file, but my current approach to writing the file doesn't save much time when compared to loading the whole file into memory and then dumping it back into the file system.

For writing I'm currently:

1. opening "tempFile" in append mode
2. appending bytes [0, N) to the temp file
3. appending the buffer
4. appending [N + pageSize, fileSize]
5. doing os.rename ("tempFile", "fileName")

Since I have an int that points to the beginning of where buffer was taken from, and another that says what length buffer was originally, would there be any way to replace only the N bytes that were modified, instead of making a whole copy of the file and then moving it?

Comment: If this is a binary file, so that your editing does not change the SIZE of the buffer, then yes, you can use "w+b" mode and replace a block in the middle of the file.  Notice that this is totally unrelated to complexity.  Regardless of how you do it, it will still be O(N).

Comment: If you want to work with existing filesystems (e.g. through POSIX APIs), then no; these APIs allow writing at positions, but they don't have any particular support for "inserting" or "deleting"; you have to implement insertions or deletions (by shifting everything) yourself, meaning you will have linear time complexity in the size of the file.

Comment: Theoretically though, there is nothing that would prevent a file system from offering special, efficient support for insertions. If files are stored as B-Trees of chunks without keys, using only ranks (counts), then you can do logarithmic time insertions of chunks; this gives you linearithmic insertion time (in the count of the inserted chunks, not in the size of the file). Using bulk insertions of multiple chunks it should even be possible to achieve O(n + lg n). But again, this is just theory, I know of no file system that does this (but you may find databases that do this for BLOBs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When treating a file as *binary*, you can certainly replace *fixed length* data at a particular file offset:

```lua
local file = assert(io.open('data', 'w+b'))

-- write three unsigned longs
file:write(string.pack('LLL', 11, 22, 33)):flush()
-- offset by the size of one unsigned long
file:seek('set', string.packsize 'L')
-- overwrite the second unsigned long
file:write(string.pack('L', 42)):flush()
-- rewind
file:seek('set')

local a, b, c = string.unpack('LLL', file:read(string.packsize 'LLL'))

file:close()
assert(os.remove 'data')
               
print(a, b, c) -- 11, 42, 33
```

This is quite common, but leaves your file open to data corruption if any given write operation *fails*.

Given

> read, browse, and edit a large *text file*

though, the typical *text* file contains *variable length* (usually lines of) data.

Trying to directly replace a section of text with a *smaller* amount of data will lead to stale data remaining in the file (the *tail* of the previous data). Overwriting a section of text with a *larger* amount of data leads to data loss, when you overwrite the data that followed the original data.

If you are truly replacing a fixed amount of text (e.g., uppercasing a section of ASCII), then this is not too much different from dealing with binary data, except you may (will) run into problems on certain platforms that perform text mode translations (e.g., [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/file-translation-constants?view=msvc-170), when [over]writing a newline (LF)).

Your approach of appending data to a temporary file, and then renaming the file is incredibly common, and is good practice as it leaves a paper trail that is easier to follow when things go wrong, and generally offers more control over the process.

If we presume `file:read` and `file:write` (ultimately [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) and [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite)) to be O(n), then everything mentioned is O(n).

Comment: Their approach in particular ensures that there is no corruption; it makes the file write "atomic". In your binary file example, only one of the two writes could get through, leaving you in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Yes, in general, the approach of directly writing to the target file is fragile; if you do multiple small writes, it's possible that only some of them get through, and if you do a single large write, a partial write is more likely.

Comment: Right. I'll add a caveat.